# cifrar las contraseñas de superusuario

Tags: django, base-de-datos, seguridad

Buenas tardes:

Tengo dudas con respecto al acceso seguro a las bases de datos de django. Para tener acceso normalmente se tiene un super usuario y su contraseña en texto plano, o así lo he visto, en un fichero de configuración el que puede ser visto, cúales serían las opciones para cifrar las contraseñas para que no puedan ser vistas.

A ver tal vez no me explique bien, cuando se configura en el setting la base de datos, se pone el usuario y la contraseña con la que se va acceder a la base de datos. Esta contraseña aunque se cifre se pondrá en texto plano y sabiendo el mecanismo de encriptación se puede obtener. mi pregunta es si hay maneras de almacenar esta contraseña sin que se pueda ver y si se encripta no se vea en el momento de acceso el mecanismo de desencriptar

Comment: mientras más precisa sea la pregunta más rápido encontraras la solución.

Comment: Las contraseñas son cifradas en django por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Las puede cifran cuando las crea, hay diferentes formas de hacerlo para que las contraseñas no se vean, por ejemplo una contraseña "admin" se viera así "nvr4946gopjgv5049jeo".

En el insert el campo de la contraseña lo puede hacer así:

```
sha1(md5("campo_contraseña"))
```

Espero haberle entendido.